# Read time value in SAS of the form 515 as 5:15

Tags: sas

i have variable with time values like 515 which should be read like 5:15
To do this I used the following code-

```
data flights;
set cs.flights;
format sched_dep_time hhmm. dep_time hhmm. ;
run;
```

but i get result for 515 as 0.09 
which I think is the time it is calculating from 12:00 am in seconds .
 I  also use time. format but no use.
how do i deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

A format only changes the way a value is displayed.  In this case we need to change the actual value, such that it represents the number of seconds since midnight.

The following approach serves (along with the time_diff as requested):

```
data flights;
  sched_dep_time=515;
  dep_time=1215;
  format sched_dep_time dep_time time_diff hhmm. ;
  sched_dep_time=hms(round(sched_dep_time,100)/100
    ,mod(sched_dep_time,100),0);
  dep_time=hms(round(dep_time,100)/100
    ,mod(dep_time,100),0);  
  time_diff=sched_dep_time-dep_time;
  put (_all_)(=);
run;
```

gives:

```
sched_dep_time=5:15 dep_time=12:15 time_diff=-7:00
```

Comment: isnt there a simpler way to do this? I actually want to calculate the time difference between two time numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, SAS stores time values as number of seconds since midnight. So the value 515 is 515 seconds after midnight.  To get the value that represents 05:15 you need to do some conversions.

SAS has an INPUT function which is used to read character data, and you can specify the format of the data.  This allows use to read the character value '0515' and convert it to the numeric 18900 which represents the time 05:15.

Below uses the PUT function to convert the numeric value 515 to the character value '515', and the INPUT function to covert that to 18900.  The time format makes 18900 print as 05:15:00.

```
data have;
  sched_dep_time=515;
  dep_time=1515;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  SchedDepTime=input(put(sched_dep_time,4.),hhmmss.);
  DepTime=input(put(dep_time,4.),hhmmss.);
  format SchedDepTime DepTime time.;
  put (Sched_Dep_Time SchedDepTime Dep_Time DepTime)(=);
run;
```

returns:

```
sched_dep_time=515 SchedDepTime=5:15:00 dep_time=1515 DepTime=15:15:00
```